# how to download form data in admin panel of joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I have a requirement to download form data in admin panel of joomla,i working in Joomla! 3.6.2 now i am facing some problem,my form extension name is form maker lite when some one submit form data of form show in admin panel but how to download all data of form and how to forward form data to some other user of my joomla site by Users manage menu.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: What kind of research have you done?